# How to disable scrolling in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains many elements. It is scrollable. What I'd like to do is disable scrolling on this specific div. Is there a way to disable scrolling in one div rather than the whole page?

Comment: CSS: overflow: hidden; Now there will be no scroll bars, but you can programmatically scroll.

Comment: You can also use [body-scroll-lock](https://github.com/willmcpo/body-scroll-lock).

Comment: add the css height:auto; so your containt not hide ,but height will be increased